# Help with date formats

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

What's the correct format to parse this string:

"Mon, 14 Mar 2011 15:36:00 GMT"

into a NSDate using NSDateFormatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strPubDate];
```

Comment: >_< it works on iphone simulator! but it does not work on the real device! maybe a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: And with `dd` instead of `d` ?

Comment: it works! you rock guy!!! =) Often we spend a lot of time in really trivial issues! however, nice pic! :-p

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithString:@"Mon, 14 Mar 2011 15:36:00 GMT"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: Sorry for the identical answer. @malinois was faster and I didn't see it until I posted mine.